# Intentionally Reproduce App Crash "Application has Stopped Working" On JavaFX windows App

Tags: java, windows, javafx, javafx-8

I'm writing a **JavaFX** app exclusively for **Windows**, where the app is required to crash and produce a generic `"Application has Stopped Working"` **Error Dialogue** as seen [here](https://img.raymond.cc/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/program_has_stopped_working_error.png) when the client uses a pirated serial key for the app's activation.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: `System.err.println("Application has stopped working"); System.exit(1);`?

Comment: @fabian Oh sorry i wasn't clear, the client should be introduced with the "Application has stopped working" dialogue, you see [here](https://img.raymond.cc/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/program_has_stopped_working_error.png). I'll edit my question

Comment: Not really sure exactly what you're looking for. You could just hang it intentionally: `Platform.runLater(() -> { while (true) ; });`. That would make it non-responsive, not sure if it is enough for Windows to detect it has "stopped working". But why not just show your own modal dialog and exit when it closes?

Comment: I would assume you can not "reproduce" this without having the knowledge if this is reproducable on your clients system. It might be a different JDK or other systems (like AV or malware) could interfere the normal work. This is normal "debugging hell".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Alert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) class with the [ERROR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.AlertType.html#ERROR) alert type.
Below is a working example:

**MyApplication.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        // do something
        throw new RuntimeException();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        displayApplicationError();
    }

}

private void displayApplicationError() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        new ApplicationError().start(new Stage());
        Platform.exit();
    });
}
```

**ApplicationError.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("ERROR");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("Application has Stopped Working");
    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

[image]

The alert will have a native look and feel on Windows, you can find more examples [here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/).